# Personalizing Table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, chapters, capitalization

I want to make my table of contents to have the words "Chapter", "Title" and "Page" written in uppercase, like "CHAPTER", "TITLE" and "PAGE". My document class is Book. How can I do it?

Comment: Please provide additional information (e.g. the document class). A minimal working example would be even better.

Comment: Solution found, I simply edited the style file of my document class! Not a very good idea, but it worked :D

Comment: Rather than editing the question title as "[SOLVED]", you should write a separate (self-)answer.

Comment: A better option might be to use the `titlesec` package as described in [this question about the table of contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18127/table-of-contents)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For customizing the table of contents, you could use a dedicated package, such as

- [tocloft](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft)
- [titletoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc)

If you would like to change certain commonly used names, check if they are stored in a macro. There are common macros such as `\chaptername`, `\partname`, etc. You could redefine it, which would allow consistent use through the complete document, such as

```
\renewcommand*{\chaptername}{CHAPTER}
```

If you use the babel package, which is very recommendable, you should do it a bit differently, using the `\addto` command, otherwise babel would override your definition. Here's a complete example for you:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\addto{\captionsenglish}{%
  \renewcommand*{\chaptername}{CHAPTER}
  \renewcommand*{\pagename}{PAGE}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
See \pagename~1.
\end{document}
```

In your comment you said that you changed the style file. I would never do that since it would have effect on each other file which uses that class or style, respectively. Instead, I would use `\renewcommand` or `\renewenvironment` in the document preamble, copying the original definition there and making my changes - just in my own preamble, leaving the class/style untouched.