# Table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18127/table-of-contents)

How will i create a table of contents to have an output look like this?
hope you can help me. Sorry for the incomplete data of my question last time.

Table of Contents

ILLUSTRATIONS ...........................................i

TABLES...................................................ii

ACKNOWLEDGEMENT..........................................iii

ABSTRACT.................................................iv

Chapter 1

INTRODUCTION..............................................1

```
    1.1 MySQL ..........................................2
    1.2 Java............................................3
    1.3 C++................................................4
```

Chapter 2

THEORETICAL CONSIDERATIONS...........................5

```
      2.1 Records Management.....................6
           2.1.1 Entity-relationship diagram.....7
```

Chapter 3

SUMMARY, CONCLUSIONS, AND RECOMMENDATIONS.............45

```
   Summary.........................................56
   Conclusions.....................................57
   Recommendations.................................58
```

Appendix

```
   Appendix A Interview Questions..................96
   Appendix E User Guide...........................1023
```

BILIOGRAPHY............................................1024

and then once i open the content "ILLUSTRATIONS", I can see content look like this:

ILLUSTRATIONS

```
 2.1 One-to-one relationship......................8
 2.2 One-to-many relationship.....................9
 2.3 Many-to-many relationship....................11
```

and so when i go to the content " TABLES", I can see this:

TABLES

```
 2.1. MySQL Numeric Types..........................13
 2.1. MySQL Date and Time Types....................15
```

hope you can share your knowledge...