# tocloft, listoffigures, listof=totoc, KOMA: not in tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, tocloft

This MWE illustrate the problem:

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc]{scrreprt}
%\usepackage{tocloft}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\chapter{test}
\begin{figure}
\caption{test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

without the package `tocloft` the `listoffigures` will be included in the `tableofcontents` but with `tocloft`, the "List of Figures" is not in "Contents". What can I do to have the `listoffigures` in `tableofcontents`?

Comment: Do you _need_ `tocloft`? I'm asking because there's also KOMA's `tocstyle` package for adjusting the TOC which should be nicely compatible with all of KOMA-Script's options

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Do you want to have the ToF merged into the ToC or just having it after the ToC but with an header somehow smaller than "Contents" to show that the ToF is a part of the ToC?

Comment: As already said, we really need to know what you actually want here!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea based on this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14545/31058):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\mytoc{%
    \tableofcontents
    \section*{Figures}%
    \@starttoc{lof}%
    \bigskip
    \section*{Tables}%
    \@starttoc{lot}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mytoc

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{figure}
\caption{testfig 1}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\begin{table}
\caption{testtable}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
\caption{testfig 2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This gives me the following output:

[image: Output with the above code]

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Therefor KOMA provides `listof=leveldown`