# List of Figures and Tables in same page

Tags: table-of-contents

I would like to have my list of figures and my list of tables in the same page. I don't want only one list, the numberings must be independent. Now I have

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,titlepage,headinclude]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\newcounter{dummy}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\listoftables
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

It works well with the numbering but it preserve two different headings for each list. I would like an output like this in the same page:

> List of Figures and Tables
>
> Figure 1 .... Page 4
>
> Figure n .... Page n
>
> Table 1 .... Page 2
>
> Table n .... Page n+1

Comment: What you're asking for can be done by modifying the definitions of `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`. However, those definitions are class-specific. You need to tell us which class you're using by editing your question and adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Are you using a report/book class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show \listoffigures and \listoftables on one page and in the toc?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14510/how-to-show-listoffigures-and-listoftables-on-one-page-and-in-the-toc)

Comment: @lockstep, I saw that question but they propose a single numbering scheme. I am using scrreprt.

Comment: @lockstep the formatting makes this a different question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses the [`titletoc`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/titletoc) package to help with the formatting.

[image: screenshot]

There are a couple of important things in the code below:

```
\begingroup
\makeatletter
%\listoffigures
\chapter*{List of Figures and Tables}
\@starttoc{lof}
\let\clearpage\relax
%\listoftables
\@starttoc{lot}
\makeatother
\endgroup
```

This enables us to use our own title for the combined list of figures and tables by using the `\@starttoc` command; note that it is used twice, one for each of the `lof` and `lot`.

The customization of each entry is achieved using

```
\titlecontents{figure}
[0pt]                                  % left margin
{\addvspace{.5cm}}%                    % above code (e.g vertical space)
{\contentsmargin{0pt}                  % numbered entry format
    Figure~\thecontentslabel%
    \large}
{\contentsmargin{0pt}\large}           % unnumbered entry format
{\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\contentspage}    % filler-page format (e.g dots)
%[\addvspace{.5pc}]
```

You can tweak this as you see fit.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: on}
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,titlepage,headinclude]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{table}
[0pt]                                  % left margin
{\addvspace{.5cm}}%                    % above code (e.g vertical space)
{\contentsmargin{0pt}                  % numbered entry format
    Table~\thecontentslabel%
    \large}
{\contentsmargin{0pt}\large}           % unnumbered entry format
{\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\contentspage}    % filler-page format (e.g dots)
%[\addvspace{.5pc}]                    % below code (e.g vertical space)

\titlecontents{figure}
[0pt]                                  % left margin
{\addvspace{.5cm}}%                    % above code (e.g vertical space)
{\contentsmargin{0pt}                  % numbered entry format
    Figure~\thecontentslabel%
    \large}
{\contentsmargin{0pt}\large}           % unnumbered entry format
{\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\contentspage}    % filler-page format (e.g dots)
%[\addvspace{.5pc}]                    % below code (e.g vertical space)


\begin{document}

\begingroup
\makeatletter
%\listoffigures
\chapter*{List of Figures and Tables}
\@starttoc{lof}
\let\clearpage\relax
%\listoftables
\@starttoc{lot}
\makeatother
\endgroup

\newcount\tmp
\tmp=0
\loop
\advance\tmp by 1
\begin{table}[!htb]\caption{}\end{table}
\begin{figure}[!htb]\caption{}\end{figure}
\ifnum\tmp<5 \repeat
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it does exactly what I want and works perfectly.

Comment: @CeciliaGuerra you're very welcome :)