# Add figures and tables to the same page in order of appearance

Tags: table-of-contents

Is there a way to make tables and figures appear in the same TOC, in order of appearance in the document, but numbered separately? Exactly like [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162681/list-of-figures-and-tables-in-same-page), but with the tables and figures mixed together in order of page number? I know this sounds odd, but I have an application that specifically requires this format.

EDIT: Thanks to [Jagath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/25852/jagath-ar), the main issue is solved. However, this has upset the formatting a little. To use his MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,tocloft}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\listfloatname}{List of Floats}
\newlistof{float}{flt}{\listfloatname}
\long\def\@caption#1[#2]#3{%
\par
\refstepcounter{float}%
\addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
 {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
\addcontentsline{flt}{float}%
 {\protect\numberline{\csname thefloat\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
\begingroup
\@parboxrestore
\if@minipage
  \@setminipage
\fi
\normalsize
\@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3}\par
\endgroup}
\makeatother
% my formatting 
\renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{Table }
\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{Figure }
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnum}{:}
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{:}

\begin{document}
\listoffloat
\listoftables
\listoffigures

\newpage
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\caption{First figure.}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{First table.}
\end{table}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{Second figure.}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}
\caption{Second table.}[h]
\end{table}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you can achieve using `tocloft` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,tocloft}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\listfloatname}{List of Floats}
\newlistof{float}{flt}{\listfloatname}
\long\def\@caption#1[#2]#3{%
  \par
  \refstepcounter{float}%
  \addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
    {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
  \addcontentsline{flt}{float}%
    {\protect\numberline{\csname thefloat\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
  \begingroup
    \@parboxrestore
    \if@minipage
      \@setminipage
    \fi
    \normalsize
    \@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3}\par
  \endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffloat

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\caption{First figure.}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}
\caption{First table.}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$M_i$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$m$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$G'_i$}  \\ \hline
      28,3 & 1 & 22 & 43  \\
      28,4 & 3 & 25 & 141
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\caption{Second figure.}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}
\caption{Second table.}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$M_i$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$m$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$G'_i$}  \\ \hline
      28,2 & 2 & 21 & 80  \\
      28,4 & 3 & 25 & 141
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

If the numbering should be seperate then change:

```
  \addcontentsline{flt}{float}%
    {\protect\numberline{\csname thefloat\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
```

to

```
  \addcontentsline{flt}{float}%
    {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
```

The difference is to change `\csname thefloat\endcsname` to `\csname the#1\endcsname`.

Updated Answer:

The following code will generate the PDF with float names.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,tocloft}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\listfloatname}{List of Floats}
\newlistof{float}{flt}{\listfloatname}
\long\def\@caption#1[#2]#3{%
\par
\refstepcounter{float}%
\addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
 {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
\addcontentsline{flt}{#1}%
 {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
\begingroup
\@parboxrestore
\if@minipage
  \@setminipage
\fi
\normalsize
\@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3}\par
\endgroup}
\makeatother
% my formatting 
\renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{Table }
\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{Figure }
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnum}{:}
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{:}

\begin{document}
\listoffloat
\listoftables
\listoffigures

\newpage
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\caption{First figure.}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{First table.}
\end{table}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{Second figure.}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}
\caption{Second table.}[h]
\end{table}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works like a charm. I was using \renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{Table } and \renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{Figure } to provide labels - is there a way I can adapt them? I thinkthat I need to edit the flt class, but cftfltfont obviously is not defined - I'd have to make that a command?

Comment: Sorry. I couldn't quiet get it. Could you please post a minimum working example, so that I can help you :-)

Comment: Sure, I'll add it to an edit in my question. Thanks again!

Comment: @JPJanet: Could you please check the new code appended to my answer.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! If I could accept it twice...