# Making modifications to numbering in \ref when overwriting \caption

Tags: cross-referencing, labels, tocloft

I'm using this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316932/add-figures-and-tables-to-the-same-page-in-order-of-appearance) to control the appearance and order of float captions in a document. The relevant part is:

```
\renewcommand{\thetable}{S\arabic{table}}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\listfloatname}{\normalsize Contents:}
\newlistof{float}{flt}{\listfloatname}
\long\def\@caption#1[#2]#3{%
\par
\refstepcounter{float}%
\addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
 {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
\addcontentsline{flt}{#1}%
 {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{ #2}}%
\begingroup
\@parboxrestore
\if@minipage
  \@setminipage
\fi
\normalsize
\@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3}\par
\endgroup}
\makeatother
```

This is used to label floats in order of appearance in  a certain document. However, when I try and use `\ref` to reference a float, the additional S character does not appear. It works perfectly if I remove the above section, but I need to retain the functionality.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{S\arabic{table}}
%% TOC handling
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\listfloatname}{\normalsize Contents:}
\newlistof{float}{flt}{\listfloatname}
\long\def\@caption#1[#2]#3{%
\par
\refstepcounter{float}%
\addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
 {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
\addcontentsline{flt}{#1}%
 {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{ #2}}%
\begingroup
\@parboxrestore
\if@minipage
  \@setminipage
\fi
\normalsize
\@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3}\par
\endgroup}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \caption[Short title]{A table \label{table:a_label}}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        1 & 2 \\
        3 & 4
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    As in \ref{table:a_label}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As I can see the `\@caption` is totally changed for all floats then? Why should `\thetable` be called by your 'float' counter caption at all? This is weird!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer  I confess I don't really understand how the \caption is redefined. It is supposed to count the total number of floats, so that it can produce a sorted contents list in order of appearance in the document. But the caption label (in the table) does have the S, so it must call the \thetable...

Comment: With 'order of appearance' you mean the order in the output document, not in the order of specification?

Comment: Yes, in the output document. I needed to make a single contents list for all floats, in the order in which they appear in  the final document. I got this code from Jagath's answer to the linked question, and it does exactly what is required, but it breaks \ref

Comment: The answer is quite easy (after thinking :D)

Comment: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This took me some minutes to understand why the reference is wrong.

Well, the `table` counter is increased already by the `\caption` command, before `\@caption` is called, so `\refstepcounter{float}` will overwrite the `\@currentlabel` definition, which is used by `\label` to write the relevant information to the `.aux` file.

Solution: As long as your particular float shall not be referred to as `float` don't use `\refstepcounter` but `\stepcounter`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{S\arabic{table}}
%% TOC handling
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\listfloatname}{\normalsize Contents:}
\newlistof{float}{flt}{\listfloatname}
\long\def\@caption#1[#2]#3{%
\par
\stepcounter{float}% No refstepcounter here!
\addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
 {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
\addcontentsline{flt}{#1}%
 {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{ #2}}%
\begingroup
\@parboxrestore
\if@minipage
  \@setminipage
\fi
\normalsize
\@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3}\par
\endgroup}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\listoffloat
\begin{table}
  \caption[Short title]{A table \label{table:a_label}}
  \begin{tabular}{c|c}
    1 & 2 \\
    3 & 4
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
As in \ref{table:a_label}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing you're doing is creating a `.flt` file to contain each of your floats (perhaps a combination of `figure`s and/or `table`s), you don't have to redefine the entire `\@caption`. Instead, insert the relevant contents addition using an [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) patch; it's much cleaner:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft,etoolbox}

\renewcommand{\thetable}{S\arabic{table}}

\newcommand{\listfloatname}{\normalsize Contents:}
\newlistof{float}{flt}{\listfloatname}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@caption}% <cmd>
  {\addcontentsline}% <search>
  {\addcontentsline{flt}{#1}{\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{#2}}%
   \addcontentsline}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffloat

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption[Short title]{A table \label{table:a_label}}
  \begin{tabular}{c|c}
    1 & 2 \\
    3 & 4
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
As in \ref{table:a_label}.

\end{document}
```

---

You may even get away with adapting `\addcontentsline` to insert content into an `.flt` file every time it is sent content that should go into the `.lof` or `.lot`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\thetable}{T\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{F\arabic{figure}}

\newcommand{\listfloatname}{\normalsize Contents:}
\newlistof{float}{flt}{\listfloatname}

\let\oldaddcontentsline\addcontentsline
\renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{%
  \oldaddcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}% Default addition to contents file
  \ifnum\pdfmatch{#1}{lot,lof}=1 % A table or figure...
    \oldaddcontentsline{flt}{#2}{#3}% ...also add to .flt
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\listoffloat

\section{A section}

A table~\ref{tbl:table} and figure~\ref{fig:figure}.

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption[Short title]{A table \label{tbl:table}}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption[Short figure]{A Figure \label{fig:figure}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```