# automatic new page when using \tableofcontents etc

Tags: table-of-contents

I use `\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}` on a MAC 10.9.2 running LaTeX TeXshop 3.35. How do I suppress the new page command which seems imbedded in the macros `\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures`, `\listoftables`?

Thanks

Comment: `\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\endgroup`

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How to show `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` on one page and in the ToC?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14510/5764)

Answer (score 3):

This is not very usual. You can locally `\let` the `\clearpage` command internally used to be `\relax`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany] {book}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]