# How to show \listoffigures and \listoftables on consecutive pages?

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking

Is it possible to put the list of figures and tables onto consecutive pages? The default configuration inserts a white page between both lists.

```
\listoffigures
\listoftables
```

I have found [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14510/how-to-show-listoffigures-and-listoftables-on-one-page-and-in-the-toc?newreg=a924e4e50b8246e4ad6677ed5eeec42b) to put the list of figures and tables onto one page, but what I'd like is to clear the page after the list of figures.

Comment: Which documentclass do you use? Please show a MWE.

Comment: @TeXnician I'm using `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,hidelinks,openright]{report}`