# Remove newpage before \printindex

Tags: page-breaking, indexing

I want to remove the new page before `\printindex`

```
\phantomsection
\renewcommand{\indexSectionCount}{\myeval{\SectionCount-1}}
\renewcommand{\indexname}{B~Stichwortverzeichnis}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{B~Stichwortverzeichnis}
\preto\endtheindex{\par\nobreak\noindent}
\printindex
```

This is my code

Comment: welcome, can you provide a MWE, i.e., from \documentclass{..}... to \end{document}?

Comment: Maybe `{\let\newpage\relax\printindex}`? It might be necessary to redefine a different page breaking macro. Compare e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14511/2975 where this technique is used for other lists.

Comment: How this might be done very much depends on what `\documentclass` you are using, as well as the formatting of the index.  A multi-column index isn't easy to graft onto any kind of document halfway down the page.

Comment: ```{\let\newpage\relax\printindex}``` does not work for me in ```documentclass{article}```. I used: ```\usepackage[nonewpage]{imakeidx}```